# Make a project for sharing files(images and databases) with 2 other projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, project

I am currently working on a PC application (C# WPF) and the application requires images, however some times there will be new images and so I add them to the project. A friend of mine is working on the Web application (C# ASP.net MVC3) and he also uses the same "resources". Now when there are new images, we have to add them both to our project in a folder(images).

Now the question:

Is it possible to make some sort of project that we both can use so we just have to add the images to that project? (We can sync the project with Git). Because it is kinda annoying that we both have to add the images to our projects(solutions).

PS: The pc app and webapp will be the same so it will always require the same images / database files(sqlite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a folder structure that both of you can share, then you can add the images to a common folder that is accessible to both your projects. If not you can create a resource only DLL called a satellite assembly which can host the images and can be used by both applications.